# distinct performance on large table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose I have a table with a column that has repeats, e.g.

```
Column1
---------
    a
    a
    a
    a
    b
    a
    c
    d
    e
    ... so on
```

Maybe it has hundreds of thousands of rows.  Then say, I need to pull the distinct values from this column.  I can do so easily in a `SELECT` with `DISTINCT`, but I'm wondering on performance?

I could also give each item in Column1 an id, and then create a new table referenced by Column1 (to normalize this more appropriately).  Though, this adds extra complexity to making an insert, and adds in `joins` for other possible queries.

Is there some way to index just the distinct values in a column, or is the normalization thing the only way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index on column1 will considerably speed up processing of distinct, but if you are willing to trade some space and some (short) time during insert/update/delete, you can resort to [materialized view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx). This is indexed view you might consider as dynamic table produced and maintained following view definition.

```
create view view1
with schemabinding
as
   select column1, 
          count_big(*) cnt
     from theTable
    group by column1
-- create unique clustered index ix_view1 on view1(column1)
```

(Do not forget to execute commented create index command. I usually do it this way so that view definition contains index definition, reminding me to apply it if I need to change the view.)

When you want to use it be sure to add [noexpand hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) to force use of materialized data (this part will remain mistery to me - something created as performance enhancement is not turned on by default, but rather activated on spot).

```
select *
  from view1 (noexpand)
```